# Bash while read : output issue

Tags: sql, bash, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Updated :
Initial issue :
Having a while read loop printing every line that is read
Answer : Put a done <<< "$var"
Subsequent issue :
I may need some explanations about some SHELL code :
I have this :

```
temp_ip=$($mysql --skip-column-names -h $db_address -u $db_user -p$db_passwd $db_name -e "select ip_routeur,code_site from $db_vtiger_table where $db_vtiger_table.ip_routeur NOT IN (select ip from $db_erreur_table);")
```

That gets results looking like this :

```
<ip1>   <site1>
<ip2>   <site2>
<ip3>   <site3>
<ip4>   <site4>
```

up to 5000 ip_address

I did a "while loop" :

```
while [ `find $proc_dir -name snmpproc* | wc -l` -ge "$max_proc_snmpget" ];do
    {
         echo "sleeping, fping in progress";
         sleep 1;
    }
done
temp_ip=$($mysql --skip-column-names -h $db_address -u $db_user -p$db_passwd $db_name -e "select ip_routeur,code_site from $db_vtiger_table where $db_vtiger_table.ip_routeur NOT IN (select ip from $db_erreur_table);")
while read ip codesite;do
{
    sendSNMPGET $ip $snmp_community $code_site &
}
done<<<"$temp_ip"
```

And the sendSNMPGET function is :

```
sendSNMPGET() {
touch $procdir/snmpproc.$$
hostname=`snmpget -v1 -c $2 $1 sysName.0`
if [ "$hostname" != "" ]
then
    echo "hi test"
fi
rm -f $procdir/snmpproc.$$
```

The $max_proc_snmpget is set to 30
At the execution, the read is ok, no more printing on screen, but child processes seems to be disoriented

```
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
./scan-snmp.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
./scan-snmp.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
./scan-snmp.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
./scan-snmp.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Why can't it handle this ?

Comment: It does it beacuse you are creating too many processes. Try looking at the value of $$ and seeing if it is changing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't seem to have liked my answer with GNU Parallel, I'll show you a very simplistic way of doing it in parallel without needing to install that...

```
#!/bin/bash
MAX=8
j=0
while read ip code
do
   (sleep 5; echo $ip $code) &   # Replace this with your SNMPGET
   ((j++))
   if [ $j -eq $MAX ]; then
      echo -n Pausing with $MAX processes...
      j=0
      wait
   fi
done < file
wait
```

This starts up to 8 processes (you can change it) and then waits for them to complete before starting another 8. You have already been shown how to feed your `mysql` stuff into the loop by other respondents in the second to last line of the script...

The key to this is the `wait` which will wait for all started processes to complete.

Comment: Well, sorry i searched for Parallel, but not able to install it on Redhat. Plus this will cause some troubles when moving on the server (as i will not be present...)

I tried your solution, it is working, i just had to change the done < file by done<<<"$var" (because of the printing)

Answer (score 3):

If `temp_ip` contains the name of a file that you want to read, then use:

```
done<"$temp_ip"
```

In your case, it appears that `temp_ip` is not a file name but contains the actual data that you want.  In that case, use:

```
done<<<"$temp_ip"
```

Take care that the variable is placed inside double-quotes.  That protects the data against the shell's word splitting which would result in the replacement of new line characters with spaces.

#### More details

In bash, an expression like `<"$temp_ip"` is called *redirection*.  In this case in means that the `while` loop will get its standard input from the file called `$temp_ip`.

The expression `<<<"$temp_ip"` is called a *here string*.  In this case, it means that the `while` loop will get its standard input from the data in the variable `$temp_ip`.

More information on both redirection and here strings in `man bash`.

Comment: If you can explain how `<<<` and what is the difference in `<` and `<<<` !

Comment: `echo Hello > a`, then: `cat < a` will print `Hello` while `cat <<< a` will print `a`.

Comment: Thanks, working ! But now having another issue... updated thread

Comment: @Gui if your original problem is solved, please don't change your question beyond recognition. Leave this question so that the current answers are relevant and make a new question if you need help with something else.

Comment: Well, it's a subsequent issue with this answer, i guess it can be solved in the same thread... No ?

Comment: @Gui no, because it's a separate issue. The first problem was about using `read`. That problem has been solved and you have accepted an answer. I suggest that you undo your edit, post another question and if you want, you can refer back to this one.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can parse the output of your initial command directly:

```
$mysql --skip-column-names -h $db_address -u $db_user -p$db_passwd $db_name -e "select ip_routeur,code_site from $db_vtiger_table where $db_vtiger_table.ip_routeur NOT IN (select ip from $db_erreur_table) | \
while read ip codesite
do
...
done
```

If you want to improve the performance and run some of the 5,000 SNMPGETs in parallel, I would recommend using GNU Parallel ([here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)) like this:

```
$mysql --skip-column-names -h $db_address -u $db_user -p$db_passwd $db_name -e "select ip_routeur,code_site from $db_vtiger_table where $db_vtiger_table.ip_routeur NOT IN (select ip from $db_erreur_table) | parallel -k -j 20 -N 2 sendSNMPGET {1} $snmp_community {2}
```

The `-k` will keep the parallel output in order. The `-j 20` will run up to 20 SNMPGETs in parallel at a time. The `-N 2` means take 2 parameters from the `mysql` output per job (i.e. ip and codesite). {1} and {2} are your ip and codesite parameters.

http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Answer (score 1):

I propose to not *store* the result value but use it directly:

```
while read ip codesite
do
    sendSNMPGET "$ip" "$snmp_community" "$code_site" &
done < <(
  "$mysql" --skip-column-names -h "$db_address" -u "$db_user" -p"$db_passwd" "$db_name" \
         -e "select ip_routeur,code_site from $db_vtiger_table where $db_vtiger_table.ip_routeur NOT IN (select ip from $db_erreur_table);")
```

This way you start the mysql command in a subshell and use its output as input to the while loop (similar to piping which here also is an option).

But I see some problems with that code:  If you really start each `sendSNMPGET` command in the background, you very quickly will put a massive load on your computer.  For each line you read another active background process is started.  This can slow down your machine to the point where it is rendered useless.

I propose to not run more than 20 background processes at a time.